# Exchange global address list (GAL) access from unix

Tags: unix, exchange-server, addressbook, gal

What are the ways of accessing exchange global address list(GAL) and doing some operation on them (like finding manager of a contact, etc.) in unix?
This can be done in pretty straightforward way in VBA Outlook App in windows. I am trying to find out a way of doing that in unix environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as LDAP is accessible on your exchange server, you can use that. Here is a small script I wrote to do just that, showing the ldapseach command it uses internally:

```
$ 411 -d -e joe.user
   command is "/usr/bin/ldapsearch -y ${HOME}/.ssh/temp -x -b dc=ACME,dc=com -H ldap://app.corp.company.com:3268 '(mail=joe.user@*)'"
                Joe User    555 329 3485 joe.user@acme.com,  NY
```

A few comments:

- at prior companies, you could do an unauthenticated bind. That was easier.
- you can see I store my password in my .ssh directory temporarily. this is bad in theory
- you can probably use any LDAP client. I wanted a simple script with no dependencies, so I parse ldapsearch output

Comment: Thank you in coming up the idea on LDAP. I am figuring out the settings for our exchange server. I will reply back once I get through the precess.

Comment: An LDAP browser with a GUI is good to use to explore and figure out the arguments to use. Jexplorer is one. http://jxplorer.org/

Comment: Thank you so much! It took some time to get ldap and do all the settings correctly. But finally it is so worth it! I migrated my tool completely to linux servers from my local windows machine. Now it is much more powerful and maintainable than the Outlook VBA I had (which I mostly never cared to understood).